# How do i install another version of PhP?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, php5

I would like to have installed WHMCS on my dedicated server. (I already have installed apache2)
How do I install PhP 5.4 as WHMCS not support PhP 5.5?

WHMCS System requirements: http://docs.whmcs.com/System_Requirements

I use ubuntu 14.04 & apache2

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/CHH/phpenv

There is one more version manager https://github.com/wilmoore/php-version, but I would give a try to phpenv, because I am using rbenv and it works fine.

Comment: Ehm, how do i install phpenv? ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods of solving the issue you are encountering, you can try the following methods:

**METHOD 1** :: FRESH INSTALL

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get remove --purge `dpkg -l | grep php | grep -w 5.5 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs`
sudo apt-get purge apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
sudo sed -i.bak "s/trusty/precise/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-suexec libapache2-mod-fcgid php5-cgi
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-ming php5-ps php5-pspell php5-recode php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl php5-xdebug
sudo sed -i "s/precise/trusty/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
dpkg --get-selections | egrep '^(apache|php)' | sed 's/install/hold/g' | sudo dpkg --set-selections
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install  mysql-client mysql-server phpmyadmin
```

This will install the following Packages:

Apache
fcgid
PHP 5.4
MySQL
PHPMyAdmin
and a few other software (including popular PHP Extensions)

---

**METHOD 2** :: MULTIPLE PHP VERSIONS

This method assumes that you have Installed Git (and Nano) on your server

1) Install Dependencies (IF you haven't already):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git apache2-mpm-worker libapache2-mod-fastcgi php5-fpm
```

2) Install PHP Dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep php5
```

3) Download PHP Farm:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/cweiske/phpfarm.git /opt/phpfarm
```

4) Navigate Directory:

```
cd /opt/phpfarm/src
```

5) Compile PHP Versions (of your choice):]

Full list of all versions is available here: http://museum.php.net

**NOTE!** Install location is /opt/phpfarm/inst/bin when finished.

PHP 5.4: `sudo ./compile.sh 5.4.0`
PHP 5.5: `sudo ./compile.sh 5.5.0`
PHP 5.6: `sudo ./compile.sh 5.5.6`

6) Enable FAST-CGI

```
sudo a2enmod actions fastcgi alias
```

7) Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

8) Create FastCGIServer Config

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf.d/php-cgisetup.conf
```

9) Edit FastCGIServer Config

You will need to have one line for each version of PHP that you created with PHPFarm, Use (CTRL+O) to save and (CTRL+X) to close.

```
#php-cgi setup
#used for multiple php versions
FastCgiServer /var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi-5.4.0
FastCgiServer /var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi-5.5.0
FastCgiServer /var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi-5.5.6
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin-php/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
```

10) Create CGI-BIN

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/cgi-bin
```

11) Create PHP-CGI File (for Specific PHP Version)

For Example (for PHP 5.4):

```
sudo nano /var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi-5.4.0
```

12) Edit PHP-CGI File

```
#!/bin/sh 
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=3 
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN 
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000 
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 
exec /opt/phpfarm/inst/bin/php-cgi-5.4.0
```

**Note**: If you wish to compile another version of PHP, then just replace the "php-cgi-5.4.0" on both step 11 and 12 with php-cgi-X.X.X", where X.X.X stands for the PHP Version your after

13) Set CGI-BIN Owner

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/cgi-bin
```

14) Set CGI-BIN Permissions

```
sudo chmod -R 0744 /var/www/cgi-bin
```

15) Navigate to Directory

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

16) Create Virtual Hosts

```
sudo nano php-dev
```

17) Edit Virtual Hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName **PHP 5.4 HOSTNAME GOES HERE**
DocumentRoot /var/www 
 <Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   AddHandler php-cgi .php
   Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.4.0
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
 LogLevel warn
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName **PHP 5.5 HOSTNAME GOES HERE**
 DocumentRoot /var/www
 <Directory />virtual host
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   AddHandler php-cgi .php
   Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.5.0
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
 LogLevel warn
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName **PHP 5.6 HOSTNAME GOES HERE**
 DocumentRoot /var/www
 <Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   AddHandler php-cgi .php
   Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.5.6
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
 LogLevel warn
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

You will have to configure this to your needs.

18) Disable Default Website

```
sudo a2dissite default
```

19) Enable the New Website

```
sudo a2ensite php-dev
```

20) Navigate to the WWW Directory

```
cd /var/www
```

21) Reload Apache

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

22) Remove Old Index

```
rm index.html
```

23) Create a Test PHP Page

```
sudo nano index.php
```

24) Edit the Test Page We've made

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

25) Get your Server IP Address

If you don't know how, use the following command:

```
ifconfig
```

26) Open the /etc/hosts file

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

27) Edit the Hosts File

```
127.0.0.1 YOURWEBSITEURLFORPHP54.COM
127.0.0.1 YOURWEBSITEURLFORPHP55.COM
127.0.0.1 YOURWEBSITEURLFORPHP56.COM
```

and that's that, you can now save this, and Reload/Restart Apache if you need to and test your new websites, which run on different php versions!